# Convert timestamp fields

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium

it is possible to convert fields like io.debezium.time.ZonedTimestamp
to
org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp
?
trying with

```
"transforms.TimestampConverter.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
"transforms.TimestampConverter.field": "setted,synchronized,dlm,created,dlm",
"transforms.TimestampConverter.unix.precision": "microseconds",
"transforms.TimestampConverter.target.type": "Timestamp"
```